# Which HTTP error codes should I create custom error pages for?

Tags: apache, http

I think it makes sense for 404, since it is very likely that the user may have typed in an incorrect url.

But I'm not sure about the others - I would rather not waste bandwidth and send only minimal error pages back as content if users are not going to see it.

Comment: This question is effectively asking for a survey of what other people do; it's off topic for SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My personal selection:

```
401: Unauthorized
403: Forbidden
404: Not Found
500: Internal server error
```

Note that you can have all these pages point to a single php script that will take care of the fancy decoration, and the only variable part will boild down to the error code and name.

You might want to do a special case for 404, but the others are either caused by server failure (if you see these too often, it's time to have a word with your provider) or a user forcibly wandering where he should not (typically trying some raw urls to see if he can access a hidden part of your site), so I expect the niceties should be reduced to the bare minimum :).